# Create session before each Unit test

Tags: java, junit, playframework, playframework-2.1

I want to drive Unit tests with Play 2.1.1 which depend on user being logged in or authentification through API keys. I would like to do something like this:

```
/**
 * Login a user by app, email and password.
 */
@Before
public void setSession() {
    session("app", "app")
    session("user", "user0@company.co")
    session("user_role", "user");
}
```

Could someone indicate me the right way or is there another approach which allows me to separate the login function from single unit tests? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Since in Playframework, there is no server side session as in the Servlet API ([Playframework uses cookies](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.x/JavaSessionFlash)), you have to simulate the session for each request.

You can try using the [FakeRequest.withSession()](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/api/2.1.x/java/play/test/FakeRequest.html#withSession%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29):

```
private FakeRequest fakeRequestWithSession(String method, String uri) {
    return play.test.Helpers.fakeRequest(method, uri).withSession("app", "app").withSession("user", "user0@company.co").withSession("user_role", "user");
}

@Test
public void badRoute() {
  Result result = routeAndCall(fakeRequestWithSession(GET, "/xx/Kiki"));
  assertThat(result).isNull();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Nico! routeAndCall is deprecated it seems and I only get a Promise as Result. Is there anything else to pay attention to in Play 2.1.1?